# Custom Sharing in Salesforce community

Tags: community

We use to use custom share in Customer Portal if we wanted custom sharing to be applied. e.g Account share we use to add a new record via apex coding. Accountid & Userid in the object.

We have similar requirement in Salesforce communities. As Communities doesnnt support custom sharing ...is there any alternative to fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Which community licence type are you using - Customer Community or Customer Community Plus?

Answer (score 1):

You may have the wrong Communities license to do what you want. The Communities Plus license supports Apex Managed Sharing with the regular Customer Communities license does not.